# How can i generate a XML-Mapping on Excel-list?

Tags: excel, xml, xsd, mapping

Main purpose: I have a given XML file and a list of Customernames in Excel. I would like to create a XML Mapping, so i can generate a new XML-file with it.

My problem: Excel does not map the whole list (columns) but just a single cell.

This is my XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Profiles xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/Users/baj426/Documents/Altova/XMLSpy2018/Examples/test.xsd">
    <Profile CompanyId="" Duns="">
        <Tab name="Tab_Address" label="Address">
            <Group Name="Group_IDs">
                <Field Value="true" Name="Field_IDs_SIM_Strategic"/>
            </Group>
        </Tab>
    </Profile>
</Profiles>
```

This is my XML-Schema generated by XMLSPy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- W3C Schema generated by XMLSpy v2018 rel. 2 (x64) (http://www.altova.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Tab">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Group"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="Tab_Address"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="label" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="Address"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Field">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Value" use="required" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Name" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="Field_IDs_SIM_Strategic"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Group">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Field"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Name" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="Group_IDs"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Profile">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Tab"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="CompanyId" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value=""/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="Duns" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value=""/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Profiles">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Profile"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This is example code of how i would like to have it:

This is Example XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<shiporder orderid="889923"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

XML-File after Mapping with some values from Excel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<shiporder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <item>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <price>120</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <price>120</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <price>120</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <quantity>4</quantity>
        <price>120</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <quantity>5</quantity>
        <price>120</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <quantity>6</quantity>
        <price>120</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <quantity>7</quantity>
        <price>120</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <quantity>8</quantity>
        <price>120</price>
    </item>
</shiporder>
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel cannot export XML files with more than one (!) hierarchy level so the XML file you wish to create cannot be exported by Excel, unless you use VBA to construct the XML.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your response. What do you suggest as an alternative to achieve what i want? Other Software?

Comment: How should the XML be constructed in VBA (and is Notepad++) also possible?

Comment: Creating XML from VBA isn't very hard, you can basically just construct a large string variable containing the entire XML as text and then use VBA file functions to save the string to a file. I would suggest you give it a try and repost here with your attempts when you get stuck.